# Unicode Character Conversion

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, uitextview

I am attempting to use the unicode character U+00AE in a UITextView. If I use the code `\u{00AE}` using the below:

```
textView.text = "THING AND STUFF TrademarkedThing\u{00AE}"
```

However, if I pull some text from another location (this is technically coming from an API call, but that shouldn't matter), and assign it to the textView, I do not get the unicode character:

```
var apiText = "TrademarkedThing\u{00AE}" //Pulled from API call as text and saved into text variable
textView.text = "THING AND STUFF " + apiText
```

So the in the code below, the first unicode character does not show, but the second does.

```
var apiText = "TrademarkedThing\u{00AE}" //Pulled from API call as text and saved into text variable
textView.text = "THING AND STUFF " + apiText + " \u{00AE}"
```

Why won't the unicode from that text show?

Comment: Is that your actual code? It should be `\u{...}` with a *backslash*.

Comment: @MartinR whoops. Good catch. I've changed it above. I am using a backslash.

Comment: But I cannot reproduce the problem with your (updated) code. There are two trademark signs in the text view.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, but when the text comes from an API call (not just var text = ""), the unicode does not appear. Is this a compile time vs run time issue perhaps?

Comment: Probably an encoding issue. For debugging purposes, add an `println(apiText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)`

Comment: @MartinR on a whim, I passed from the API the ®  instead of \u{00AE} and it worked.

Comment: That Unicode conversion (from `\u{...}`) only happens for string literals. You can see the problem if you compare `let t1 = "Thing\u{00AE}"` vs `let t2 = "Thing\\u{00" + "AE}"`.

Comment: @NateCook Add as answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unicode conversion (from `\u{...}`) only happens for string literals. You can see the problem if you compare these two:

```
let t1 = "Thing\u{00AE}"
// Thing®
let t2 = "Thing\\u{00" + "AE}"
// Thing\u{00AE}
```

Since your string is coming from another source, it acts like the second one. The Swift language book has a section on [Unicode characters in string literals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_445).

---

If you want to interpret those Unicode sequences after the fact, here's a `String` extension:

```
extension String {
    func indexOfSubstring(str: String, fromIndex: String.Index? = nil) -> String.Index? {
        var index = fromIndex ?? startIndex

        while index < endIndex {
            if self[Range(start: index, end: endIndex)].hasPrefix(str) {
                return index
            }
            index = index.successor()
        }
        return nil
    }

    func convertedUnicodeSequences() -> String {
        if let index = indexOfSubstring("\\u{") {
            if let nextIndex = indexOfSubstring("}", fromIndex: index) {
                let substr = self[Range(start: advance(index, 3), end: nextIndex)]
                let scalar = UnicodeScalar(UInt32(strtoul(substr, nil, 16)))

                return self[Range(start: startIndex, end: index)] + 
                       String(scalar) + 
                       self[Range(start: nextIndex.successor(), end: endIndex)].convertedUnicodeSequences()
            }
        }

        return self
    }
}
```